# Can't Parse VmBootSource[] from HyperV Get-Firmware PowerShell Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm using powershell cmdlets in my C# code to interact with Hyper-V virtual machines. I'm specifically trying to get the bootorder of a virtual machine. I have no problem running the Get-Firmware command, but I can't seem to parse the return object and get the boot order info I need.

```
private void Test()
{
    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
    {
        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        Command command = new Command("Get-VMFirmware");
        command.Parameters.Add("VMName", "MachineName");
        pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

        PSObject result = pipeline.Invoke().First();
        var bootorder = result.Properties["BootOrder"].Value;

    }
}
```

Per the documentation (and when I look at the value of result.Properties["BootOrder"].Value in locals) I believe my bootorder variable should be a Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VmBootObject[], but I can't seem to find that namespace so I can't cast it as such. So, bootorder is type object, and I can't get any information out of it. What am I doing wrong here?